# VBA - Como procurar palavras de uma lista em outra e apontar "Encontrado"

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Bom dia.

Empaquei, nessa.

Na **plan1 coluna A** tenho uma lista com 20 palavras diferentes.
Na **plan2 Coluna C** tenho textos complexos em cada célula.

Preciso percorrer a **plan2 Coluna C** procurando palavras contidas na **plan1 Coluna A** se a palavra for encontrada na **Plan2 Coluna D** aparecerá a mensagem *"encontrado"*, caso não *"oculto"*.

Agradeço demais!

Comment: Mike, não dá para entender muito bem seu problema. Poste seu código, uma imagem da planilha, o que você desenha mais claramente, pois dessa forma fica complicado.

Comment: Seja bem-vindo(a). Por favor faça o [tour], depois leia [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas) e crie um [mcve] para a pergunta. Pois a pergunta está muito ampla e quando [você é mais específico](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1481/75104), há mais chances de sua pergunta ser respondida corretamente. Com um exemplo [da tabela](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)

Answer (score 1):

O código abaixo percorre a coluna C da plan2 procurando pelas palavras da coluna A da plan1, escrevendo na coluna D da plan2 "encontrado", caso tenha encontrado alguma das palavras ou "oculto", caso não tenha encontrado nenhuma.
Inclua o código abaixo em uma macro na sua planilha.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim linhas1 As Long
    Dim linhas2 As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    linhas1 = Worksheets("plan1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    linhas2 = Worksheets("plan2").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To linhas1
        For j = 1 To linhas2

            If (Worksheets("plan2").Cells(j, 4) <> "encontrado") Then

                a = InStr(1, Worksheets("plan2").Cells(j, 3), Worksheets("plan1").Cells(i, 1), 1)
                If (a = 0) Then
                    Worksheets("plan2").Cells(j, 4) = "oculto"
                Else: Worksheets("plan2").Cells(j, 4) = "encontrado"
                End If

            End If

        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Renata, Valeu demais!

Comment: @MikeCunha Favor ler [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/75104)

Answer (score 0):

Pra isso não é preciso usar o VBA, uma formula no Excel já te serviria:
=SE(SEERRO(LOCALIZAR(A1;Plan2!$A$1);0)>0;"Encontrado";"Oculto")

Mas se precisar que seja feito no VBA é algo do tipo:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim texto As String, palavra As String

    texto = Sheets(2).Range("A1")
    palavra = Sheets(1).Range("A4")

    If texto Like "*" & palavra & "*" Then
        MsgBox "Encontrado"
    Else
        MsgBox "Oculto"
    End If
End Sub
```